# Regex to validate textfield with csv format using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried with the following regular expression

> /^([a-z0-9])+(,[a-z0-9]+)*$/

My text field string looks like the following csv format as

> 123,456,789,012

But the above expressions fails for me, main thing is whitespaces are not allowed with the given text field string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432408/regular-expression-to-match-csv-delimiters

Comment: Why are you using those parentheses?

Comment: @Pez what are your valid and invalid inputs ?

Comment: @ Sujith PS (123, 234, 345) be a invalid pattern and {123,345,567} be a valid one

Comment: @Pez So you dont want to allow whitespace , right . what about ( ) and  { } ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to validate textfield with value like csv format ,

   you can use :    `/^([a-z0-9]+(?:,[a-z0-9]+)*)$/gm`

   Which will accept `123,456,789,012`

   And will reject
   `123, 456, 789, 012`     // Those containing spaces
2. If you want to match something like this (num,num,num,num)

   you can use :

   `/^(\([a-z0-9]+(?:,[a-z0-9]+)*\))$/gm`

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tR2kZ4)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here's the version with white-spaces allowed:

```
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+(?:, ?[a-z0-9]+)*$/;
!!pattern.exec('123,456,789,012'); // true
!!pattern.exec('123, 456, 789, 012'); // true
```