# Simple perl split() and Regular Expression question

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I parse quoted CSV in Perl with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633607/how-can-i-parse-quoted-csv-in-perl-with-a-regex)

I am attempting to take a CSV file and import each row into an array (where each element represents a column). The format of a CSV file is very simple:

```
item1,item2,item3
nextrowitem1,item2,item3
"items,with,commas","are,in,quotes"
```

I imported the CSV file using:

```
open(FILE, "test.csv");
@lines = <FILE>;
```

Then I looped through it using:

```
foreach(@lines){
    @items = split(/regular expression/);
    /*Do stuff with @items array*/
}
```

(Note that you do not need to use `split(/regular expression, $string);` because `split()` assumes `$_` if no string is supplied)

Before I tested the file using a CSV file where none of the items contained commas and the simple regular expression of `split(/,/)`. This worked just fine, so there is nothing wrong with the file, reading it, or my loop after this regular expression. However when I hit items that contained a comma they got understandably divided like so:

```
1 => "items
2 => with
3 => commas"
4 => "are
5 => in
6 => quotes"
```

Instead of the desired:

```
1 => items,with,commas
2 => are,in,quotes
```

Can anyone help me develop a regular expression to split this array correctly? Basically if the item starts with a quote (`"`), it needs to wait until `","` to split. If the item does not start with a quote, it needs to wait until `,` to split.

Comment: Thank you for linking to that =) Definitely a duplicate - in fact, his question went into even more detail than mine. I will look into CPAN now to see if I can make use of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reading [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) as a possible option that already does this. The problem with doing parsing of a CSV into a regular expression is that you have to look for things like `","` (which you indicated) as well as just a `,` separation.

Comment: I agree. You can't do CVS splitting with a regular expression since commas and quotes can be in a CVS field. The only real way is to break up the line bit by bit in a loop. Text::CVS does the magic for you.

Comment: @David, [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) and [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) are _very_ different.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately, I'm dyslexic and am working with a project which uses CVS. The confusion was bound to happen. I meant "CSV".

Answer (score 5):

Just use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) instead...

Comment: Or use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV), which uses Text::CSV_XS for speed if it can, but also has a pure-Perl implementation in case you don't have a C compiler.

Answer (score -1):

See my [post that solves this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428053/validation-using-regular-expression-in-c-net-applicaiton/6429039#6429039) for more detail.

`^(?:(?:"((?:""|[^"])+)"|([^,]*))(?:$|,))+$` Will match the whole line, then you can use the matched captures to get your data out (without the quotes).

Comment: What does it mean when an expression starts with a question mark? I know that `^ab?` will match `a` or `ab`, but what's the significance of `^(?:....`? I've never seen a question mark at the beginning...

Comment: This is a job for a CSV module as suggested by other answers not a regex

Comment: `(?:expression)` means a non-capturing group.  This prevents the regex engine from tracking parts of the string that match that part of the expression.  Look at $1, $2, $3, etc.  here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html