# Regex/Jquery - Return empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression

I'm sorting through a CSV file splitting (using `.match()`) on commas outside of quotes, and what I have so far is working:

```
/"[^"]*"|[^,]+/g
```

The only problem is that there are several areas where the string might be something like:

```
...,xxx,,xxx,...
```

and what I want to have happen is that I get a an array from that of:

```
[...,xxx, ,xxx,...]
```

but instead I get

```
[...,xxx,xxx,...]
```

changing it to

```
 /"[^"]*"|[^,]*/g
```

doesn't work out so well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Provide some sample input values.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428053/validation-using-regular-expression-in-c-net-applicaiton/6429039#6429039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change your original regexp to also add empty elements if you have sequences of `,,`. It doesn't add an empty element for `"a",`, but i assume that's not what you want

The regexp is:

```
/"[^"]*"|[^,]+|(?=,,)/g
```

Example usage:

```
var input = 'ACP,Something,,"Some long, sentence, with commas",other things';

var matches = input.match(/"[^"]*"|[^,]+|(?=,,)/g);

console.log(matches); // ["ACP", "Something", "", "\"Some long, sentence, with commas\"", "other things"]
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uzaDeRe/1/edit

Comment: I'm using string.match(), not split, sorry about that. The regex works for what I'm doing except that if there is a ",," area in the string, it doesn't return anything instead of returning an empty item.

Comment: I think i understand what you want now. Check my edited post please.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I'm not too familiar with regex yet, could you explain the (?=,,) part? I'm assuming it is just checking for ',,'.

Comment: It is called positive lookahead. Basically checks if the following characters are `,,`, but does not consume them! So this matches any empty string that is followed by two commas. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace function like this:

`var str = yourString.replace(/,,/g,', ,')`

And after that you will get what You need with your regex, hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: This solution seems to add some unwanted spaces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use replace. Instead split on a regexp `values.split(/super awesome regexp/)` However, you probably want better control. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428053/validation-using-regular-expression-in-c-net-applicaiton/6429039#6429039) for a better solution.

Comment: this splits on every non comma

Answer (score 0):

Silly question: Why are you using a regexp here?

```
console.log("aaa,xxx,,xxx,,yyy,zzz".split(","));

> ["aaa", "xxx", "", "xxx", "", "yyy", "zzz"]
```

Comment: Because the string i'm splitting looks something like "ACP,Something,,"Some long, sentence, with commas",other things"

So it would break on commas inside of quotes.